# QPainter.drawText italic writes outside of the rectangle

Tags: qt

I'm using `QPainter::drawText` to... well... draw some text, but I have an issue when using fonts in italic where the text is written outside of the given `QRectF`.

Here is a sample code:

```cpp
    void TestApplication::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        QRectF rect(100,100,100,100);
        QRectF necessary;
        QFont font("Times New Roman", 30);

        font.setItalic(true);   
        painter.setFont(font);  

     
        painter.fillRect(rect, QColor(0,255,0));
        painter.drawText(rect, Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter, "ff",&necessary);
    }
```

With this, the output produced is:

[image]

As you can see, the first f is written outside of the defined `QRectF`. If i write enough text the same will happen in the right hand side. I already tried adding `Qt::TextDontClip` to the flags but it produced no effect.

Can somebody help me?

**EDIT**:

As explained in the answer this is the expected behavior. I've been able to work around it by using `leftBearing` (the explanation is in the answer) like so:

```cpp
    void TestApplication::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
    {
        QPainter        painter(this);
        QRectF          rect(20,20,100,100);
        QRectF          textRect;
        QFont           font("Times New Roman", 40,0,true);
    
        font.setItalic(true);   
        painter.setFont(font);
    
        QFontMetrics    fontMetrics(font);  
    
        textRect = rect.adjusted(-fontMetrics.leftBearing('f'), 0, fontMetrics.leftBearing('f'), 0);
    
        painter.fillRect(rect, QColor(0,255,0));
        painter.drawText(textRect, Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop, "ff");
    }
```

Producing the expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to deal with this it to reduce the Rect before drawing the text, if the text is italiced: -

```
QRectF rect(100,100,100,100);

QRectF textRect = rect.adjusted(8, 0, -8, 0);

painter.drawText(textRect, Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter, "ff",&necessary);
```

As the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawText-10) states, when passing in the boundingRect rect as the last argument: -

> The boundingRect (if not null) is set to the what the bounding rectangle should be in order to enclose the whole text.

So, it's not going to necessarily be bound by the rect you pass in.

Note that the QFontMetrics class allows you to get the boundingRect required for rendering a string: -

```
QFont font("Times New Roman", 30);
QFontMetrics fontMetrics(font);

fontMetrics.boundingRect("ff");
```

However, the [documentation for QFontMetrics](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-2) states: -

> **Note that the bounding rectangle may extend to the left of (0, 0), e.g. for italicized fonts, and that the width of the returned rectangle might be different than what the width() method returns.**

So what you are seeing is expected behaviour.

Comment: I forgot to mention I had tried this approach too, but it has the undesirable effect of adding an extra space if the string starts with a non-problematic character. 

Your last edit gave me an hint, though. If I understand correctly I could use 

    fontMetrics.leftBearing('f');

but the result of this is only 1 whereas the necessary indentation is about 8px. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sounds right to me. Though it depends upon what it means by "logical origin of the character" in the docs. Perhaps this explanation of rendering characters may help; http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-3.html

Comment: Ok, I feel very dumb right now. The leftBearing method actually produces the wanted result. I was just creating the fontMetrics in the wrong place (before italicizing the font).

Comment: No problem, we got there in the end ;O)